# Splitting column into two in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am working with this current data frame right now in R and my goal is to use the separate function in tidyr to separate the songs_genre column into two:

```
songs <- c("Wheel in the Sky", "Smooth Criminal", "Bloodstream", "New Kid in 
Town", "You Belong with Me")
length <- c(211, 209, 299, 304, 232)
genre <- c("Rock", "Pop", "Pop", "Classic Rock", "Country Pop")
songList <- data.frame(songs, length, genre)
songList
songUnite <- unite(songList, "songs_genre", c("songs", "genre"), sep=".")
songUnite
```

However, when I enter in the command to separate:

```
songSeparate <- separate(songUnite, col = songs_genre, into = c("songs", "genre"), sep=".")
songSeparate
```

this warning appears:

> Warning message: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 5 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].`

I have checked online to see if my formatting and variables are all in the right place but can't seem to find the error in what I have written.

I have also included library (tidyr)

Answer (score 6):

You have 'escape' the `.` with `sep = "\\."`.

`.` is a special regex character that matches any character unless escaped. Better to use separators such as `_` to avoid this issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue and found this while searching- I had used separators "." and "|" but was getting each digit as a column when I tried to separate. Using "_" as a separator resolved my issue. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can also split a column using the package `stringr`:

```
require(stringr)

# data:
twowords <- c("hi there", "there how", "how are", "are you")

### split into two columns:
dat <- data.frame(
  word1 = str_extract(twowords, "\\w.*(?=\\s)"), # regex says: match if you see space on the right
  word2 = str_extract(twowords, "(?<=\\s)\\w.*") # regex says: match if you see space on the left
   )
dat
  word1 word2
1    hi there
2 there   how
3   how   are
4   are   you
```